# DataWindow displays contents in Debug, but not in RunTime

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I inherited this Powerbuilder 12.0 project.  We needed to add another datawindow (which is more or less a copy of another datawindow, but with different sql tables tied to it).

When testing the datawindow in Debug mode, the "report" shows up just fine, data and the formatting.  Then after deploying the application, running the executable only displays a blank white page for that same datawindow -- no data and no formatting.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Did the pbd with the new datawindow get deployed?

Comment: What Slapout said plus... is the datawindow object being assigned dynamically, maybe based on some business rules this "new" one is assigned? If so, then you probably need to look at what Jason said, the object is probably not being compiled into the EXE because it wasn't specified in .PBR file so add it to PSR or build to PBD's.
Also, check that you used the same database connection "when editing" the new datawindow control. For example did you log in as the schema owner when you should not have, and the tables are not prefixed with schema and they should be?

Comment: Thanks!  Let me try that.  As a workaround, I had to piggyback on a different datawindow that had a nearly similar layout (stubbed on one column), and made use of an UNION statement.  :)   That is a kludge I'd like to do away with though.

Comment: Ok, looks like I cannot generate a PBR file.  Once I can, I'll try what Slapout and DisplacedGuy said.  The PBR file that we have has a very old timestamp which means that it needs to be regenerated with the new datawindow info and all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First guess, as [Slapout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19072/slapout) suggests, is that the datawindow didn't get deployed. Either compile everything to PBD or include a reference to the datawindow in a PBR file.

Second guess: An error on retrieval?

Comment: The comment made by Slapout in the comment section is the winner... because it was not specified in the PBR file.  D'oh me.  Thanks all!